# jqGrid Unload and jqGrid Destroy

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I'm having an issue on jqGrid Unload and Destroy functions.

I have called jqGrid Unload and re-create the jqGrid. However, the row ID still running. For example, I have added 2 rows(ID: 0 and 1) into jqGrid(1st time), then Unload and re-create the jqGrid(2nd time) but when I'm inserting a new row of data, the row ID is 2 instead of 0.

I have also tried jqGrid Destroy but I'm not able to re-create the jqGrid through calling my function of jqGrid creation.

The following is my codes to Unload and re-create:

```html
$.jgrid.gridUnload("#jqgrid");
    alert("Un load");
    loadScript("js/plugin/jqgrid/grid.locale-en.min.js", pagefunction);
```

Comment: can you add some more description or the code because  `$("#jqgrid").jqGrid("GridUnload")` should work fine , plus which version of the grid are you using

Answer (score 1):

Please specify the version used in order to get correct answer. GridUnload function was modified hard in our [Guriddo jqGrid](http://www.guriddo.net) release, where the old one has a lot of problems.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

it depends on whether you are loading the grid initially with data from server or creating from local.  If it is the latter, you can reference from this blog https://kisdigital.wordpress.com/2010/02/25/jqgrid-the-hard-way/ under the function deleteRow().